# Any technical specs of the 1978 Battlestar Galactica?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-1978

Are there any official technical specifications for the original series Galactica online?

I know there's a [Battlestar Wiki](https://en.battlestarwikiclone.org/) but I'm not sure how reliable it is.

Comment: Out-of-universe construction blueprints; http://www.galactica.tv/battlestar-galactica-1978-news/the-official-battlestar-galactica-blueprints.html

Comment: I don't have it any more, but as a child I had a "Battlestar Galactica Annual" (don't recall which year it was, but there can't have been many, given how short lived the show was). This included at least rough specs for Galactica, vipers and I think some cylon craft.  Edit: pretty sure it was [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Battlestar-Galactica-copyright-Universal-Studios/dp/B000VUQ7LK).

Comment: (Of course, having been produced entirely by outside contractors, the canonicity of anything included in such a book is somewhat dubious, but I'm reasonably sure it doesn't flat out contradict anything that was seen on screen, at least)